# How can I create a Dictionary from an Enum?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create a dictionary of enum values?
Example below what I need.

**Example**

```
key = 0, value = "Unknown"
key = 1, value = "Another"
etc..
```

**Code snippet of enum**

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Another = 1,
    ...
}
```

**My attempt**

```
 var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyeNum));
 var namesames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyeNum));


 // Save values
 foreach (var i in values )
 {
     dictionaryList.Add(i, "");
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dictionary<int, string> values = 
     Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
         .Cast<MyEnum>()
         .ToDictionary(e => (int)e, e => e.ToString());
```

Comment: Based on the OP, it looks like you have the key and value swapped around.

Comment: @ledbutter you are right, thanks! Didn't notice that (possibly it was not clear in first edit of question)

Comment: yeah thanks, I noticed that as well..  That's a really good snippet of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

 foreach (var v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
     dict.Add((int)v, v.ToString());
```